# Coordinate geometry - understanding question

Tags: geometry

[image]

The diagram shows the sketch of a straight line $my - x = n $

The point$(-6,0) $ is reflected onto point $(2,0)$ in the line $ x=k.$ find the value of k

I do not understand the question "reflected onto point..."

My view .. -
I thought that the line (curved) cut the X axis at 2 points . (-6,0) and (2,0), but I still does not know what does $x=k$ mean... Can I get a hint ?

Comment: the line $x=k$ is perpendicular to the x-axes

Answer (score 1):

Since it refers to the set of points at which the coordinates are $(k,y)$, for all values of $y$, the phrase "the line $x=k$" is the equation of a line which is vertical.  The problem tells you what value $(-6,0)$ has after being reflected in that vertical line, and asks you to find out where the line must be.